# Cut off with indirect object

Tags: collocations

As far as I understand, when a line of communication or supply is interrupted, it can be said like this:

> They cut off electricity yesterday.

Is it correct? At least Google shows this collocation is often used.

Now what if I want to give additional information as to who exactly was cut off. Can I use indirect object like for the verb *give*?

> They cut off us electricity.

Or should I say:

> They cut off electricity to us

And if neither is correct, how would you say it?

Answer (score 4):

Your second sentence ("They cut off us electricity") is incorrect, and your third is seemingly correct, judging by a Google Books search:

> When they dismissed us, they cut **off electricity to** the villages outside Nablus. (Staughton Lynd, ‎Alice Lynd, ‎Sam Bahour, 1994)

Another option is getting rid of the idea to use an indirect object (or a prepositional phrase like "to us") in favor of the [possessive determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive_determiner) **our**:

> A severe winter storm **cut off our electricity** for almost a week. (Angelyn J. Keegstra, ‎Shana Galen, 2015)
>
> It went on and on. Then they **cut off our electricity**, which cut off our water supply. (Morgan & Kennedy, 2004)